# How can I check if my application can create a symbolic link?

Tags: java, java-7

From my Java application I want to create a symbolic link. However my application can run in different circumstances, not all of those permit the creation of symbolic links. I have the following situations:

1. Linux - can always make a symlink
2. Windows - can make a symlink if you are running the application as an administrator.

To create the symlink I use [`Files.createSymbolicLink()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createSymbolicLink-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-). This throws an `IOException` under Windows when it doesn't have permission. To be precise the exception is:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: test\link: A required privilege is not held by the client.
```

I want to be able to tell if I have this permission from the application (Java 7 or newer) before trying to make the symlink. How can I do this?

Comment: Hmm, I'm curious as to what this actually does under Windows? The way to do it is probably to try and create one in `System.getenv("java.io.tmpdir")` in a static initializer or something and have the method act accordingly, or something like that

Comment: Yes, that's what I have done so far, but it doesn't strike me as very elegant. Under windows you just get a symbolic link (same as you get with the `mklink` command).

Comment: You can only test by trying to do the operation (or use heuristics to make a qualified guess).  You know that exceptions can be caught?

Comment: You don't want to test it before you try it at all. You want to try the operation and catch the exception if it fails.

Comment: In this case I want to ignore a test case if the system it runs on doesn't allow them. I can also imagine situations where you don't want to start a procedure at all when you know the symlink at the end of it can not be created.

Comment: Regarding the suggestion of  Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: this would be an anti-pattern to use exceptions as a measure of application flow

Answer (score 1):

This code bellow will work only for Windows and comes with Java.

```
public static boolean AdminAuth() {
    String groups[] = (new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem()).getGroupIDs();
    for (String group : groups) {
        if (group.equals("S-1-5-32-544"))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The SID S-1-5-32-544 is the id of the Administrator group in the Windows operating system.

You can also take a look at this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) regarding Application Manifest for Windows.